# Installing an npm Library in an Existing React Native App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, npm

I am trying to install libraries from npmjs.com and save them as dependencies on my existing react native app. Installation instruction say to write `npm install twit` in terminal. So, in VScode, with the application open, I enter this in the terminal. After installation, the terminal will say something like:

```
+ react-native-twitter@0.2.1
added 3 packages, removed 945 packages and updated 1 package in 14.238s
```

Now I cannot run the application on the android simulator etc.

Can someone explain what I may be doing wrong and what kinds of libraries I can/cannot add? For example, must the library be built specifically for react/react native?

Thanks

error when running simulator:

> react-native run-android
>
> Command `run-android` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm
>   install` and that you are inside a react-native project.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android: `react-native run-android`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/admin/.npm/_logs/2019-01-03T03_13_17_686Z-debug.logPackage.json:

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8",
    "react-native-twitter": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try *"react-native": "0.57.0"*

Comment: How do you mean? When do I try this?

Comment: You use **"react-native": "0.57.8"**. Try to **"react-native": "0.57.0"**. It may be work.

Comment: I have made this change in my package.json and then ran npm install twit and the same issue persists

Answer (score 1):

Can you tell the error when you run app in simulator?
Add your **package.json** file. It may be more helpful to find the answer.

You can recovery it using following step.

1. Go to **package.json** file and under the **dependency** delete **react-native-twitter@0.2.1**
2. Then delete your node file.
3. type cmd **npm install**
4. Then **react-native run-android**

Now you can run your app in previous version.